# Swift 3 , SpriteKit , how to make an objects move and disappear and appear in random spots

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

I need help on this game that i am building i am trying to make a object that is placed in the view to move by the x axis and i want more of these objects to appear in random spots and to be removed from the game as they pass, here is what i have so far

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")

    let floor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bottom")

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -10)

        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 - 490, y: self.size.height/2 - 150)
       player.setScale(1.4)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height))
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.addChild(player)

        floor.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2 - 270)
        floor.setScale(2)
        floor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: floor.size.width, height: floor.size.height))
        floor.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        floor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.addChild(floor)
       createSteps()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        player.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 3150))
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))

    }

   func createSteps() {

        let steps = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "object")

        steps.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 - 230 , y: self.size.height/2 - 100)
        steps.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: steps.size.width, height: steps.size.height))
        steps.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        steps.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        self.addChild(steps)

    }

   }
```

Comment: Without looking the code: 1) create random point (likely on y axis) , 2) create an action with completion handler that moves node and removes it, 3) loop all this. If you having problems with any of these steps, feel free to ask. To loop first two steps use action sequence with two elements. First element should be a delay (wait action), and the second element would be a block which spawns a node and moves/removes it.

Comment: Thanks, I got working